# git move without maintaining sub folder

Tags: bash, git, github

I have two folders in my repository, one named 'code' & other named 'tests'.

I want all files in 'code' to go to 'tests'. However, `git mv code tests` makes the files be in the path tests/code/FILENAME instead of the desired path tests/FILENAME.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
git mv code/* tests
```

Same as regular `mv` really.